# Effect-ts: why doesn’t T.chain chain for me?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I have what I think is a simple program:

```
import * as T from "@effect-ts/core/Effect";
import { pipe } from "@effect-ts/core/Function";
import { tag } from "@effect-ts/core/Has";

interface ConsoleModule {
  log: (message: string) => T.UIO<void>;
}
const ConsoleModule = tag<ConsoleModule>();
const log = (m: string) =>
  T.accessServiceM(ConsoleModule)((console) => console.log(m));
const program = pipe(
  log("hello"),
  T.chain(() => log("world"))
);

pipe(
  program,
  T.provideService(ConsoleModule)({
    log: (message) =>
      T.effectAsync(() => {
        console.log(message);
      }),
  }),
  T.run
);
```

But it writes only “hello” and not “world“.  I think I am missing something very basic about how `chain` (or perhaps how `pipe`) is supposed to function

Answer (score 1):

**TLRD**: in this case, using `T.succeedWith` instead of `T.effectAsync` will make the program work as you expect it to.

Based on the question's code, your understanding of `pipe` and `chain` is fine. The problem here is your usage of `T.effectAsync`. If you look up its [definition](https://github.com/Effect-TS/core/blob/645f81101bf609da9d040443286df383f55d49ac/packages/system/src/Effect/effectAsync.ts#L10) things will surely become clearer:

> Imports an asynchronous side-effect into a pure `Effect` value. [...] The callback function must be called at most once.

For instance, this would work:

```
T.effectAsync(cb => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(message)
      cb(T.unit) // if you were looking to return something, this could be a T.succeed("value") or a T.fail("some error")
    }, 1000)
  })
```

In case you're starting with Effect-TS, and considering documentation is scarce, my usual recommendation is to look through the tests and actual source code for answers.